# flash mp3 player: order by date uploaded?

Tags: php

Below is the code for the [flash mp3 player](http://www.flashmp3player.org/features.html) I'm using. Anyway I can change the order of the playlist by date uploaded rather than alphabetically?

Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/X48Wuffk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform a filemtime() on each file, store the value in your array, and perform usort() based on the array value you got from filemtime().